# Import Certificate to Machine\personal script/automation?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, certificate

Is there a automated way to perform this task:

I need to import a PFX certificate to computer / personal path on multiple IIS 7.5 servers (Windows Server 2008 R2).

I already tried with GPO but there is no way to import personal certificate using GPO.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
certutil -f -p <password> -importpfx <filePathToPFX>
```

Comment: Hi, just tried it. it is not importing to local machine \ personal.

Comment: Where store is the certificate imported to?

Comment: Current User - Personal

Comment: I just tried it and it works.  It defaults to the personal machine store.  You may want to try it using psexec -s cmd.exe command prompt to see if that works.